# Ubuntu 16.04 system halted - finding the reason

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, reboot, syslog

I have a remote server which is actually running a Qt GUI App continuously, but when I have checked last day I have seen that the software was not running  from time `Oct 25 19:40:41` and  I have checked the log for that time.

And I analyzed that some system halt or similar happens,  because the first two lines in below log show the reboot happened, but using `last -x shutdown reboot` command the time Oct 25 19:40:41 not listed, and I confirm no reboot happens.

How I can find really what happens at that time, and what cause it.

```
Oct 25 19:40:41 haris rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="802" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
Oct 25 19:40:54 haris rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="17852" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Oct 25 19:40:54 haris rsyslogd-2222: command 'KLogPermitNonKernelFacility' is currently not permitted - did you already set it via a RainerScript command (v6+ config)? [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2222 ]
Oct 25 19:40:54 haris rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 108
Oct 25 19:40:54 haris rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 104
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris NetworkManager[784]: <info>  [1540510832.5983] caught SIGTERM, shutting down normally.
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris dnsmasq[1278]: exiting on receipt of SIGTERM
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris NetworkManager[784]: <info>  [1540510835.5771] dhcp4 (enp2s0): client pid 1253 killed by signal 15
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris pulseaudio[5258]: [pulseaudio] module.c: After module unload, module 'module-null-sink' was still loaded!
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris NetworkManager[784]: <info>  [1540510835.8715] dhcp4 (enp2s0): state changed bound -> fail
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris ntpd[1655]: ntpd exiting on signal 15 (Terminated)
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris NetworkManager[784]: <info>  [1540510845.6623] dhcp4 (enp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Oct 25 19:40:54 haris rsyslogd-2039: Could not open output pipe '/dev/xconsole':: No such file or directory [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris ntpd[1655]: 127.127.1.0 local addr 127.0.0.1 -> <null>
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris NetworkManager[784]: <info>  [1540510845.6623] dhcp4 (enp2s0): state changed fail -> done
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris ntpd[1655]: 130.202.101.6 local addr 10.0.7.15 -> <null>
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris NetworkManager[784]: <info>  [1540510846.5592] device (enp2s0): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ip-config-expired') [100 120 6]
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris ntpd[1655]: 149.28.39.34 local addr 10.0.7.15 -> <null>
Oct 25 19:40:54 haris rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 10' suspended, next retry is Thu Oct 25 19:41:24 2018 [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris NetworkManager[784]: <info>  [1540510846.7133] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris ntpd[1655]: 192.73.242.152 local addr 10.0.7.15 -> <null>
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris NetworkManager[784]: <info>  [1540510846.8567] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris ntpd[1655]: 38.229.71.1 local addr 10.0.7.15 -> <null>
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris systemd[1002]: Stopped target Default.
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris ntpd[1655]: 138.68.46.177 local addr 10.0.7.15 -> <null>
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris systemd[1002]: Stopped target Basic System.
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris ntpd[1655]: 91.189.91.157 local addr 10.0.7.15 -> <null>
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris systemd[1002]: Stopped target Timers.
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris avahi-daemon[789]: Got SIGTERM, quitting.
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris systemd[1002]: Reached target Shutdown.
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris avahi-daemon[789]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp2s0.IPv6 with address fe80::6798:d2f8:9bcc:f431.
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris systemd[1002]: Starting Exit the Session...
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris avahi-daemon[789]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp2s0.IPv4 with address 10.0.7.15.
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris systemd[1002]: Stopped target Sockets.
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris avahi-daemon[789]: avahi-daemon 0.6.32-rc exiting.
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris systemd[1002]: Stopped target Paths.
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris systemd[1002]: Received SIGRTMIN+24 from PID 17834 (kill).
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris gnome-session-binary[1330]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris gnome-session-binary[1330]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris dbus[17836]: [system] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris dbus[17836]: [system] Activating systemd to hand-off: service name='org.freedesktop.login1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.login1.service'
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris dbus[17836]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1'
Oct 25 19:40:53 haris dbus[17836]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.login1'
Oct 25 19:40:54 haris systemd[1]: Starting System Logging Service...
Oct 25 19:40:54 haris systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Oct 25 19:40:54 haris systemd[1]: Started Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
Oct 25 19:40:54 haris systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
Oct 25 19:40:55 haris systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
Oct 25 19:40:57 haris kernel: [119835.529403] show_signal_msg: 17 callbacks suppressed
Oct 25 19:40:57 haris kernel: [119835.529406] ImageProceesing[5261]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fd898d5ddcc sp 00007fd6e1a3e890 error 4 in libQt5Core.so.5.11.1[7fd898b81000+549000]
Oct 25 19:40:57 haris systemd[17859]: Reached target Sockets.
Oct 25 19:40:57 haris systemd[17859]: Reached target Paths.
Oct 25 19:40:57 haris systemd[17859]: Reached target Timers.
Oct 25 19:40:57 haris systemd[17859]: Reached target Basic System.
Oct 25 19:40:57 haris systemd[17859]: Reached target Default.
Oct 25 19:40:57 haris systemd[17859]: Startup finished in 1.445s.
Oct 25 19:40:57 haris systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.
Oct 25 19:40:58 haris apache2[17847]:  * Stopping Apache httpd web server apache2
Oct 25 19:40:58 haris apache2[17847]:  *
Oct 25 19:40:58 haris systemd[1]: teamviewerd.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Oct 25 19:40:58 haris systemd[1]: teamviewerd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 25 19:40:58 haris systemd[1]: teamviewerd.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Oct 25 19:40:58 haris systemd[1]: teamviewerd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 25 19:40:58 haris systemd[1]: Stopped TeamViewer remote control daemon.
Oct 25 19:40:58 haris systemd[1]: Starting TeamViewer remote control daemon...
Oct 25 19:40:58 haris systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Oct 25 19:40:59 haris systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
Oct 25 19:41:00 haris systemd[1]: teamviewerd.service: PID file /var/run/teamviewerd.pid not readable (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Oct 25 19:41:01 haris systemd[1]: Started TeamViewer remote control daemon.
Oct 25 19:41:01 haris snapd[17845]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled and all features are available
Oct 25 19:41:02 haris whoopsie[17850]: [19:41:02] Using lock path: /var/lock/whoopsie/lock
Oct 25 19:41:02 haris snapd[17845]: 2018/10/25 19:41:02.899377 daemon.go:343: started snapd/2.34.2 (series 16; classic) ubuntu/16.04 (amd64) linux/4.15.0-36-generic.
Oct 25 19:41:02 haris systemd[1]: Started Snappy daemon.
Oct 25 19:41:02 haris snapd[17845]: 2018/10/25 19:41:02.900568 stateengine.go:101: state ensure error: Get https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/sections: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io on 127.0.1.1:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:57864->127.0.1.1:53: read: connection refused
```

## Edit

Logs before shutdown

```
Oct 25 19:40:30 haris sudo[5158]: Exiting normally, received signal 15.
Oct 25 19:40:30 haris sudo[5158]: /home/server/killall.sh: line 24: kill: 18446744073709551615: arguments must be process or job IDs
Oct 25 19:40:30 haris sudo[5158]: /home/server/killall.sh: line 25: kill: 18446744073709551615: arguments must be process or job IDs
```

Comment: That output looks like everything *after* the restart. Look at the minutes *before*.

Comment: But the logs just before shut down and reboot is about 10 second difference, `Oct 25 19:40:41 haris rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="802" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.` and 
`Oct 25 19:40:54 haris rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="17852" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
`   Also using last command I am not able see any reboot at that time.

Comment: Clue: Seems like your server was *told* to shutdown by /home/server/killall.sh. Not a hardware fault, not an OS crash, not an application crash

Comment: But is it possible to restart the pc 10 sec, I have checked that manual reboot takes 40-50 seconds